# C++ Subtract in a string with decrementation

Tags: c++, string, subtraction

First, here's my code :

```
std::vector<std::string> x = split("3 5", ' ');
int total = 0;
// then we loop over the elements
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
  // convert the string to an integer
  int n = atoi(x[i].c_str());
  total = total + n;
}

std::cout << "total = " << total << std::endl;
```

So, as you can see, this will add 3 to 5. However, I would like it to do the inverse (3 - 5).

How I can do that?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there something specific that you don't understand about the code?

Comment: I think I understand my code pretty well. However, I didn't tried a lot of thing because I don't really know what to do. I know how to do it with two number, but, eventually, if my string is (5 6 7), I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: What result would you expect when you have three (or more) numbers? "n1 n2" => n1 - n2; "n1 n2 n3" => ?

Comment: Imagine that my string is "707 65 12 43", I would like to do : 707 - 65 - 12 - 43

Comment: Well then the only thing you need to do is change the sign in the 7th line and start the loop from `i`. If you did write the code, you should know how to change it.

Answer (score 3):

The code you showed does basically all the work, since you subtract all given numbers to the first one, you need to take the first case as a special one, that is when `i == 0`.

```
...
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
  // convert the string to an integer
  int n = atoi(x[i].c_str());
  if (i == 0)
    total = n;
  else
    total = total - n;
}
...
```